# Django Admin - Allow models to be shown for is_staff users

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I need to make some Django models available for `is_staff=True` users in the Django admin interface.
I do not want to go for each user and assign them permissions or group permissions to the staff users.

Which method do I need to override in `ModelAdmin` or `BaseModelAdmin` class or is there any other simpler way?
I am using Django 1.4 Version

Comment: I don't understand. You would like restrict some model only for "staff" but you don't wont precise which users are "staff"? So how it will work?

Comment: I will use is_staff from the auth_user model to determine which users are staff. I have a requirement where the staff users (is_staff=True in auth_user model) should also perform CRUD operation on a specific model.

Comment: so use `staff_member_required` decorator, but first they must belong to this group, but you wrote that you do not want to enter in each USER and add it to the group.

Answer (score 6):

```
class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return True
```

has_module_permission checks if the model can be listed in the app labels table

Comment: This seems to be the right answer.  At least in the case where you want to use the `is_staff` flag as a blanket permission for viewing a specific ModelAdmin.  I use this `has_module_permission` in combination with the mixin mentioned by @mishbah.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
class StaffRequiredAdminMixin(object):

    def check_perm(self, user_obj):
        if not user_obj.is_active or user_obj.is_anonymous():
            return False
        if user_obj.is_superuser or user_obj.is_staff:
            return True
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return self.check_perm(request.user)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self.check_perm(request.user)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self.check_perm(request.user)
```

and all ModelAdmin(s) should inherit this class. For example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(StaffRequiredAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Please note, this code is untested.

Comment: You code looks perfectly fine. but the model does not get listed in the admin template of a staff user until and unless I specifically provide its  permission in the permission table. I just wanted to by-pass the assigning permission/group permissions. This code will come into picture once I have that model listed in my admin template for a staff user.

Comment: Keep in mind that the mixin has to be the first, since the priority of how methods are resolved is from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

> **The staff_member_required decorator**
>
> staff_member_required(redirect_field_name='next',
> login_url='admin:login') [[source]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators/#staff_member_required)
>
> This decorator is used on the admin views that require authorization. A view decorated with this function
> will having the following behavior:
>
> If the user is logged in, is a staff member (User.is_staff=True), and
> is active (User.is_active=True), execute the view normally.
>
> Otherwise, the request will be redirected to the URL specified by the login_url
> parameter, with the originally requested path in a query string
> variable specified by redirect_field_name. For example:
> /admin/login/?next=/admin/polls/question/3/.

Example usage:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I have to make use of django admin system. I do not call any view function  since I am using Django's Admin Interface.

Comment: this is admin view decorator

Comment: how do I see those models in django admin interface when I login to my website http://127.0.0.1:8287/admin/ and my user is a staff user (is_staff=True). I only see for this user - "You don't have permission to edit anything". but for admin use (is_admin=True) I see the list of all models registered.